Creating gcp Cloud Build trigger using terraform produces "repository mapping doesn't exist" error
I am trying to create a Cloud Build trigger on GCP using Terraform. I have managed to add a connection and a repository resource using Terraform, and indeed, I see the repository in the manage repositories tab in Cloud Build. But I see them as Gen 2 repositories.
When Terraform tries to create the trigger, I get an error message saying that the repository mapping doesn't exist. If I manually connect the repository, I get a Gen 1 repository in Cloud Build, and then Terraform succeeds in creating the trigger.
I tried creating a connection and a repository resource using \google_cloudbuildv2_connectionandgoogle_cloudbuildv2_repository` respectively.
But when I use the repository in the google_cloudbuild_trigger I expected to create the trigger using the repository.
Is there a way to create a Gen 1 repository through terraform, or (even better) to use a Gen 2 repository in a trigger?
Or is the repository mapping something extra that is created when I manually connect the repository but is missing from my terraform file?
Here are my resources:
resource "random_id" "ghb_token_id" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "github_token_secret" {
  project = var.project


  secret_id = random_id.ghb_token_id.hex

  replication {
    auto {}
  }
}

variable "ghb_pat" {
  type = string
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "github_token_secret_version" {
    secret = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.id
    secret_data = var.ghb_pat
}

variable "project_num" {
type = string
}

data "google_iam_policy" "secretAccessor" {
    binding {
        role = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
        members = ["serviceAccount:service-${var.project_num}@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
    }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_iam_policy" "ghb_secret_policy" {
  project = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.project
  secret_id = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.secret_id
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.secretAccessor.policy_data
}

variable "ghb_install_id" {
  type = string
}

resource "google_cloudbuildv2_connection" "ghb_connection" {
  #project = google_secret_manager_secret.github_token_secret.project
  project = var.project
  location = "<region>"

  name = "ghb_connection"

  github_config {
    app_installation_id = var.ghb_install_id
    authorizer_credential {
      oauth_token_secret_version = google_secret_manager_secret_version.github_token_secret_version.id
   }

  }

  depends_on = [google_secret_manager_secret_iam_policy.ghb_secret_policy]
}

resource "google_cloudbuildv2_repository" "my_repository" {
  project = var.project
  location = "<region>"
  name = "my_repo"
  parent_connection = google_cloudbuildv2_connection.ghb_connection.name
  remote_uri = "<url>"
}

resource "google_cloudbuild_trigger" "blogv2-trigger" {
  name = "my-trigger"
  location = "<region>"

  github {
    owner = "<owner>"
    name = "<name>"
    push {
      branch = "^<branch>2$"
    }
  }

  include_build_logs = "INCLUDE_BUILD_LOGS_WITH_STATUS"

  substitutions = {
    _AR_HOSTNAME = "<hostname>"
    _DEPLOY_REGION = "<region>"
    _PLATFORM = "managed"
    _SERVICE_NAME = "<service_name>"
    _TRIGGER_ID = "<id>"
    _AR_REPO = "<repo>"
  }

  filename = "cloudbuild.yaml"
  tags = ["gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run", "gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run-managed"]
  service_account = <service_account>

  depends_on = [google_cloudbuildv2_connection.ghb_connection, google_cloudbuildv2_repository.my_repository]
}

